# Using UML Diagrams in Visio 2013 Pro

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, diagrams, uml

I want to create a simple UML database diagram for presentation. My understanding is that the Viso shapes should be mostly complete in this regard with adding attributes, keys, etc. and then having connectors (e.g. foreign keys) between specific tables fields. But I can not see how this is meant to work?

I can drag say the "Entity" shape from the "UML Database Notation" into my document, and that gives me a nice box with a title, a primary key, and 2 other attributes and I can edit the text, but that is it. I see no way to set other keys, make a field required (other than changing the font style directly) etc., and attempting to then move the entity seems to just move the separate shapes (e.g. just moves the rect with the semi-transparent background).

[image: Entity shape]

I looked around for info, but it seems MS has changed things, e.g. there is a lot of Visio 2007 info saying to just use the "Database Properties" window, which seems to also not exist anywhere.

It clearly seems I am somehow using this wrong. What is the intended way to edit the UML shapes such as "Entity", to set attribute details, add attributes, etc. and keep them as a single "object"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're asking, but I discovered it today and it may help.

File->Options->Advanced->scroll down and check the "Run in developer mode" box.

Now there's a new right-click menu option. Right-click the shape. Choose "Show Shapesheet" to see/edit the shape design.

There's also a new DEVELOPER tab in the ribbon with dev tools.